# How make a dropdown editable in html using angular 10

Tags: html, angular, combobox

I am working in angular . I need a code to make a dropdown editable in html using angular

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Primeng library.

They have editable dropdown component.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

And if you don't want to use library, you could just get inspiration from source code